# How do I animate this box to have a pop out effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple div set up and I was wondering how I could make it have a 'pop out' effect. For example, I would like it to start as a smaller rectangle and have it animate to a slightly larger rectangle giving it the illusion that it is popping out at you.

HTML

```
<div id="submit-logged-out">
    You must be <a href="/wp-login.php?action=register">registered</a> to submit.
</div>
```

CSS

```
#submit-logged-out {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
font-size: 2em;
left: 112px;
padding: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is best done with plain CSS:

```
.popout {
    animation: popout 1s ease;
    -webkit-animation: popout 1s ease;
}
@keyframes popout {
    from{transform:scale(0)}
    80%{transform:scale(1.2)}
    to{transform:scale(1)}
}
@-webkit-keyframes popout {
    from{-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    80%{-webkit-transform:scale(1.2)}
    to{-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}
```

Then just add the `.popout` class to your box.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSsVx/2/)

Comment: Can we make this for inifite time interval ?

Comment: Its only shown once.. Can it be done in some intervals of 1 or 2 secs?